# How can I run another app when pressing the calculator key on my keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, remapping, calculator

I've a Logitech Media Keyboard 600 which features a separate button to launch the calculator. I need that quite often, but the Windows shipped calculator is useless; there are more advanced out there.

So I've installed another calculator application and want this special key start this other app instead of the default one.

Is that possible?

I'm not searching for a solution to pin the app to the taskbar and use another shortcut key to launch it.

Comment: The new calculator in Win7 is really good.  What do you find better?

Comment: E.g. PowerToys Calculator for WXP, didn't work for W7 but SpeedCrunch does. Need something with history and such.

Comment: @mark, you may want to consider that [Tim C's answer](http://superuser.com/a/194102/85708) is less invasive than the accepted answer and seems to be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try Logitech's [SetPoint](http://www.logitech.com/en-za/434/2996?section=downloads&bit=&osid=14) software? It may not let you change what program the key opens, but it's worth a try. I don't have a Logitech keyboard, so I can't check.

You could also try replacing the Calculator executable (`%windir%\system32\calc.exe`) with the other calculator, but that may be risky.

Comment: That's it! I always avoid this vendor supplied software, have had too much bad experience with it the last 15 years .. but seems time changes ;-) With this software you can configure the key to run any app you want.

Comment: Good to hear! I was guessing a little, since the Logitech website doesn't specify _which_ keys are programmable. Some keyboards have programmable keys but don't let you modify media/special function keys.

Answer (score 88):

Edit this registry key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\18\ShellExecute`

If it does not exist, create a String Value with name `ShellExecute` and as value the path to your program.

Comment: Thanks, that was also helpful and works without the need to install any software!

Comment: Mine is 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' rather than 'HKLM'.

Comment: 'HKLM' is a std. abbr. for 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'

Comment: On Windows 10 HKLM/software/microsoft/windows/currentversion/explorer/appkey/18 is empty. Edit: ShellExecute is a String Value that you have to make, and it's value should be the full path.

Comment: In my case (Windows 10) the value which was there by default was `ShellExecute=calc.exe`. Changing this to a full path of the calculator of my choice worked fine.

Comment: now for the grand prize, someone tell me how to launch a Windows 10 app from within there) There's an amazing calculator called Console Calculator in the Windows store. It's a metro app, not to be confused with the quite similar console calculator regular windows application, which is also good but I like this windows 10 app better

Comment: If you want to do this with a Microsoft Store App, follow this: https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/57000-method-open-any-windows-10-apps-command-line.html and copy the resulting command eg. `explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\42145KTFlabs.Consolecalculator_8z4z4d1rtnx0p!App` to your registry string value.

Comment: It's amazing this non-accepted answer is still working more than a decade later.

Comment: this is the way