# Bind physical "calculator" button on windows 7 to a different application

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I have a physical "calculator" button on my (Microsoft) keyboard which launches the windows calculator. I'd like to bind it to launch SpeedCrunch instead. Can it be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Great! Thanks! I should have looked harder before posting.

Comment: The Microsoft "Mouse and Keyboard Center" includes settings for the various special keys. It lets you set the application to run when the calculator button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/194102/293665), the solution is to edit

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/software/microsoft/windows/currentversion/explorer/appkey/18/ShellExecute`

Alternatively, as suggested by Brian, download the Microsoft "Mouse and Keyboard Center" and edit the button's function through it.