# What should the registry-value of a key be to execute as "Home"

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, windows-registry

I want to remap the Home-key on my keyboard so that both the Home- and Calc-key on my laptop's keyboard executes as Home - mostly because the Calc-key sits where the Home-key was on my previous laptop, and I really don't need a new calc.exe instance for every time I want to go to the top of a webpage, etc.

I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/194102/422053) which helped me find [the registry-entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FgLk.png) I need to change, but I am uncertain what I should change it to in order to to have it execute as the Home-key. Can somewhere here give me a pointer?

Comment: That registry entry is for executing programs only, not key remapping. Try using [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com) to remap Calc to Home. If that doesn't work then other solutions will need to be looked at.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. I was hoping to avoid having to install any software to achieve this. Hmm, if I delete that entry, will the button at least do nothing? @Karan

Comment: SharpKeys is portable (download the ZIP) and just a GUI frontend that makes working with Windows' own scancode mapping mechanism easy. If it detects those two keys and works then you can simply delete the EXE and the registry edit it makes will remain in effect. Let me know if it helped. Edit: No, I don't think deleting that reg key will work but you can always back it up and try.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I'll give it a go once I get back to work tomorrow, and tell you how it worked :) @Karan

Comment: A small tip: if SharpKeys doesn't list those two keys by default then try the "Type a key" feature. Good luck. :)