# Windows 10 Keyboard Shortcut to Calculator?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, calculator

On all my Windows PCs I do a 'Shortcut key' for calculator to open with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

[image: Windows 10 Calculator Properties, Shortcut tab]

I can't figure out how to do it on Windows 10. There are no right-click properties.

---

[image: Windows 10 Calculator right-click]

Comment: I just use `win`+`R` then type `calc`

Comment: I have the Logitech K520 keyboard that has an individual calculator button on the top right corner. As I do not have any Logitech drivers installed, there must be a default shortcut.

Comment: Now I found the solution. The calc button on my keyboard is the `appkey` #18 as explained here: https://superuser.com/a/194102/129262

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Option 1

- File Explorer, type this (shell shortcut) in location bar `shell:AppsFolder`, right-click Calculator, Create shorcut, Yes
- Right-click new Calculator shortcut on Desktop, Properties, there is our Shortcut key field/entry!

### Option 2

- Go to %WinDir%\System32, right-click `calc.exe`, Create Shortcut, Yes. Then step 2 above

If I placed the shortcut in %WinDir%\System or Documents it seemingly wouldn't work!? It was flakey even moving back to Desktop, but after I set the shortcut to something else, hit Apply, then back to Ctrl+Shift+C it'd work :P

Answer (score 10):

1. Create a shortcut of Calculator
2. Set the target: `C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe`
3. Right click on the shortcut and select “Properties”
4. On the “Shortcut” tab, enter the keyboard shortcut

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens to the keyboard shortcut if you delete the shortcut icon ?

Answer (score 6):

To set up a **Win+1** keyboard shortcut:

1. Pin the calculator to the taskbar (Press Windows key, start typing "calculator", once the app icon shows up, right-click to "Pin to Taskbar")
2. Drag it to the left-most spot on the taskbar (looks nice by the other white icons)
3. Windows key + 1 opens item #1 on your taskbar, which is now the calculator.
4. Bonus: Win + Shift + 1 opens a new instance of the calculator if you want multiple ones open.

Answer (score 2):

Using AutoHotkey script allows to use "Win" key for shortcut, e.g for Win+C:

```
#c::Run "calc.exe"
```

Comment: Can you please give a little more detail.

Comment: First, download and install AutoHotkey e.g. from https://www.autohotkey.com/
Then, create a new text file (e. g. "calc.ahk") and place the above script in it. Finally, run the script.
You can read more about hotkeys here: https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

Comment: Nice part about this is that you can add other shortcuts, sync this script and have all your shortcuts available on other machines you use with minimal overhead :-)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to do any programming or pollute my desktop.  What I did was find where my personal app links were stored when I installed them. I'll use Firefox as an example.

1. I clicked on the Win icon (lower left), found the Firefox icon in all the apps listed and right clicked on it.
2. In the pop-up menu that appeared I hovered over on "More" and then left-clicked on "Open file location." That directory for me was: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`.
3. I created a Desktop icon for `calc.exe` and copied it to that same directory.
4. I added the shortcut key to that Start Menu program.
5. I deleted the Desktop shortcut.

Maybe a couple extra steps, but it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Alt</kbd> - <kbd>K</kbd>) works!

Answer (score 0):

With Windows 10 you can just simply pull the calculator icon from the Windows menu to your desktop, right click it and then select properties. The window that opens should allow you to add a hotkey.

Comment: As a developer, I love to tell people it works on my machine.  However, in this case it does not.