# K780 Keyboard - Calculator Shortcut

Tags: calculator

There is no Calculator shortcut button on the K780 keyboard. I found Under "All Applications" that I could add the Calculator icon but it doesn't do anything. Is there a way to create a calculator shortcut on this keyboard?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1074946/windows-10-keyboard-shorcut-to-calculator

Answer (score 1):

The K780 Keyboard has no programmable keys
([manual](https://www.logitech.com/assets/64641/k780-online-setup-guide.pdf)).
See the article
[Shortcut and media keys for the K780 keyboard](https://support.logitech.com/en_gb/article/Shortcut-and-media-keys-for-the-K780-keyboard?product=a0q31000009kxQTAAY)
for the available keys, but none of them is for the calculator.

The only option I see is to hijack one of these shortcuts using
[AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/),
then use it to call the calculator.

The
[AutoHotkey Beginner Tutorial](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm)
could get you started.

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotkey looks a bit more complicated than I want to get into, so here is my work around: (I use Windows 10)
1) Command the search key, which is top right on my k780, between f12 and del.
   This will bring up a search panel
2) Type "c". This will start a "best match" list. In my case, calculator is on the top of the list, as calculator is a function I use often. 
3) Hit "enter" and the calculator will appear.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was a while ago but I just figured out how to create the calc shortcut!

You do need to install “Logitech Options” on your PC and then you have the option of changing <kbd>f4</kbd>, <kbd>f5</kbd>, <kbd>f6</kbd> and the command search button next to <kbd>f12</kbd>. You can simply click on one of those buttons and choose which application you would like, and calc is definitely on the list!

[image: screenshot]