# Getting desktop calculator to appear by touching one of the calculator keys on the keyboard?

Tags: desktop, calculator

Is there a way I can get my desktop calculator to appear on the monitor by simply touching one of the calculator keys on the keyboard?  (That's all I had to do when I had Windows-8)

Comment: From what I have read In windows 10 there is a Pro calculator that does this.

Comment: That or remap a key possibly>>>https://www.muo.com/tag/missing-key-remap-fix-keyboard-layout/

Comment: Possible Duplicate>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1074946/windows-10-keyboard-shortcut-to-calculator

Comment: Windows 8 didn't have such a feature. It must have been implemented by some installed keyboard program.