# How to change any multi-media key from a keyboard behavior to open a different app than the default?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, search

Based on [How can I run another app when pressing the calculator key on my keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/192763/how-can-i-run-another-app-when-pressing-the-calculator-key-on-my-keyboard)

I want to know how can I achieve the same thing but for any other key.
Say I want to make the "Search" multimedia key open the software called "Everything".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it for **any** key from the multimedia keys using the numbers described in this page.
https://web.archive.org/web/20200923183518/http://www.compiledreality.com/Home/registry-hacks/re-define-shortcut-keys-mail-home-etc

So, for this particular case, you will use number 5, search.

You edit the registry of windows adding a new key named **5** under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\
```

And then add a new "String" under the new 5 key.
Name it:

```
ShellExecute
```

And make it contain the path to everything.exe
(In your case `"C:\Program Files\Everything\Everything.exe"`)

It should look like this:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/tmzJS95.jpg]